# Joomla Page showing scrollbar rather than a fixed size

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am looking for some help in regards to a new site that I am building using Joomla 3.8. My page can be viewed at:

[http://s116169771.websitehome.co.uk/test_site/]

What I am trying to do is to create a page with a full screen image, I am not fussed about scrolling down as I will have some more data that I will add below the image but it is more to do with the scrollbar showing at the bottom as there is a gap on the right hand side and I have looked at firebug but can't locate where to fix this.

If somebody could please advise, would really appreciate it.

Comment: Edit your post ...put your website on a hypertext content because like this, we are obliged to copy past the link :/

Comment: Apologies FoxyCy corrected this now : )

Comment: At first glance I see a div with id="favslider-container-19635" that has a right margin of -15px. Setting this to 0 removes the scrollbar, but then you have a 15px white space right of your image.
It is really hard to check because the pictures keep rotating. Please stop that (or set the time to 15 seconds or so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove margin from this two place

```
.favth-row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.favth-col-xs-1, .favth-col-sm-1, .favth-col-md-1, .favth-col-lg-1, .favth-col-xs-2, .favth-col-sm-2, .favth-col-md-2, .favth-col-lg-2, .favth-col-xs-3, .favth-col-sm-3, .favth-col-md-3, .favth-col-lg-3, .favth-col-xs-4, .favth-col-sm-4, .favth-col-md-4, .favth-col-lg-4, .favth-col-xs-5, .favth-col-sm-5, .favth-col-md-5, .favth-col-lg-5, .favth-col-xs-6, .favth-col-sm-6, .favth-col-md-6, .favth-col-lg-6, .favth-col-xs-7, .favth-col-sm-7, .favth-col-md-7, .favth-col-lg-7, .favth-col-xs-8, .favth-col-sm-8, .favth-col-md-8, .favth-col-lg-8, .favth-col-xs-9, .favth-col-sm-9, .favth-col-md-9, .favth-col-lg-9, .favth-col-xs-10, .favth-col-sm-10, .favth-col-md-10, .favth-col-lg-10, .favth-col-xs-11, .favth-col-sm-11, .favth-col-md-11, .favth-col-lg-11, .favth-col-xs-12, .favth-col-sm-12, .favth-col-md-12, .favth-col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```